# Как вместо номера показать число звездочек (*)?

Tags: c

К примеру я вписываю в программу число 5 и далее мне выбивает на мониторе пять (5) звездочек (*) *****, помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Элементарный цикл for

Comment: Либо ловкий таджик, который молотком "выбивает на мониторе" звёздочки + прораб, любящий коньяк и умеющий считать звездочки.

Чисто ради шутки... оформляйте вопросы адекватнее!

Comment: Автор, вы прикалываетесь, что ли?

Comment: Не придирайтесь к автору. Судя по одному из его предыдущих вопросов, родной язык для человека - португальский.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    putchar('*');
```

Comment: Недостаточно извращённый ответ на такой простой вопрос! Я бы сделал что-нибудь наподобие [Duff's device](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B0).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#define N 5

void main()
{
    // Предпочтительно    
    char *asterisk = "**********";    
    printf("%.*s\n", N, asterisk);

    // Возможно    
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: В первом случае максимальное число выводимых звездочек будет ограничено.

Answer (score 0):

В windows можно извратиться так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char s[64] = "echo off & for /l %q in (1,1,                ) do echo|set /p=*";
  scanf("%s", s+29), (s+29)[strlen(s+29)] = 32;
  return system(s);
}
```

Они ещё и красиво медленно появляются :)